# How do I know what an apache process is doing?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

Sometimes apache goes crazy and eats all my memory and swap, but I don't know how to find out which web app is the causing it.

ps gives me this output for the process; "Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)"

```
www-data  1526  0.1 78.9 14928852 3191628 ?    D    Oct17   6:45 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I suspect Ruby+Redmine, but I want to be sure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have `mod_status.so` loaded within your apache modules then look for/add the above to your httpd.conf:

```
# Uncomment the following lines to enable mod_status support:
#
ExtendedStatus On

<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from YOUR_IP_HERE
</Location>
```

This will allow you to see all the pages being used load domain within your http server.

To access it use http://your_ip/server-status and only the ip defined at `Allow from YOUR_IP_HERE` will be able to view it.

Comment: Also I suggest to use `Allow from localhost`, so later it is possible to check that info via `lynx http://localhost/server-status` in console.

Comment: In Apache 2.4 it's Require all granted instead of Order ...

Answer (score 6):

An lsof -p  will show you what file handle it is waiting for. Also strace -p  and ltrace -p  might be handy to try to debug it.

Comment: Both very good answers :)